# Controlling multiple instances of same application with dbus?

Tags: vlc, dbus, mpris

## The problem

I'm trying to use `dbus` to control multiple instances of VLC media player from the terminal.

Using `dbus` for a single instance of VLC is no problem: as soon as VLC is started, commands like Play/Pause,

```
dbus-send --dest=org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause
```

work as expected. However, if I start a second instance of VLC, no `dbus-send` commands are ever registered by it. The first instance still register all commands fine, but the second instance does not react.

## What I've tried

#### dbus-launch vlc

I've tried using `dbus-launch vlc`. Using only `dbus-launch` creates a session bus instance and prints its unique identifying address. You can even see the instances running using `ps -aux | grep dbus`. Using the address, you can send commands with `dbus-send --address=X`.

However, when using `dbus-launch vlc`, it will not print the information about the new bus to standard output (including its identifying address). So even if I *could* send commands to it using `dbus-send`, I have no idea what address to use. There isn't a way to specify what address the news session bus instance should use either.

If I could somehow get the address of the new instance created by `dbus-launch`, the problem would (theoretically) be solved.

#### dbus-daemon

Similarly to `dbus-launch`, you can use `dbus-daemon` to create a session bus instance, but you can also specify its address with the `--address=X` flag. Using `dbus-send --address=X` gives me a "Failed to open connection [...]" error though, and even if I were to solve that I have no idea how to hook a VLC instance to that specific session bus instance. I don't know how to proceed here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found your question while looking for an answer to my own problem.  The guys over at dbus IRC channel helped me out with the answer.

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=org.freedesktop.DBus /org/freedesktop/DBus org.freedesktop.DBus.ListQueuedOwners string:org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.vlc
```

That will give you the destinations that you can loop through.  It lists them like :1.25 :1.26, so your dbus-send will look like this (note the colon is needed!)...

```
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=:1.25 /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause
dbus-send --print-reply --dest=:1.26 /org/mpris/MediaPlayer2 org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player.Pause
```